# Python requests send text with binary data

Tags: python, get, python-requests, codec

I'm trying to send both binary data and a text string (or any other normal variable) between servers using python's requests library.

I have two servers talking to each other.  **Server A** sends a GET request via python's requests library.  It looks something like this:

```
color, file_data = requests.get('https://www.serverb.com/testing', params = {...})
```

**Server B** then does something like:

```
var1 = request.args.get('var1')
var2 = request.args.get('var2')

# This function creates a binary file, saves it to disk, and returns the file name.
res = some_function(var1, var2)

file_data = codecs.open(res, 'rb').read()

return 'Success!', file_data
```

However, when I attempt this, Server B throws a 500 error.

Is what I'm attempting to do impossible?  If I can only send back the binary data, but with custom headers, that would work as well, and help on how to set those up would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An HTTP response looks like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
<headers>
<blank line>
<response body>
```

The `<blank line>` generally contains these characters - `\r\n`, also known as `CRLF`.

So, when a server sends a response, the client (or browser) can differentiate from the headers and the response body by looking at the `<blank line>`. So, anything after `<blank line>` is treated as the response body.

What that means is, there can be at most **1 response body only**. So, even if you think you're sending `color` and `file_data` separately like you're doing, they're still going in one response and the client will treat them as a single body.

---

**What you can do to get around this?**

You'll need a way to know which part of the response body is the `color` and which is `file_data`. You can do that by sending a custom header along with the response.

Let's say, your response looks like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
<headers>
<blank line>
<color><file_data>
```

Now, you can set a custom header on your response which will tell you how many bytes are there of the `color` variable.

For example, if the value of `color` is `yellow` and it's 6 characters, that means it has 6 bytes. So, you can set a custom header that would tell you the total length of `color`:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
<headers>
X-Color-Length: 6
<blank line>
<color><file_data>
```

Then, in your client side, you can get the total bytes from the `X-Color-Length` header and read that number of bytes from the body to get the value of the `color`. Example:

```
response = requests.get(...)

color_len = response.headers['X-Color-Length']

color = response.content[:color_len]
file_data = response.content[color_len:]
```

---

**UPDATE:** Now that I think about it, I've made this a little more complex than it should be. You can just send the color's value directly in a header like `X-Color: <color>`, instead of the number of bytes it has.

Comment: xyres, thanks for the quick and detailed response.  That said, the length of "color" is 5 characters, is it not?  More importantly, isn't it the length of "red" that we need to know?  And if so, the color might be "blue", which is 4 characters - how would the client know how many characters the return vale is?

Comment: @pshep123 Yes, it can be of any length. You'll have to set the header value by calculating the length of the `color` variable on the server.

Comment: Ok, I guess the bigger question is that I'm simply using the line: `return color, file_data`, not building out the whole `HTTP/1.1 200 OK...` bit.  How do I include those headers in a simple `return`?

Comment: @pshep123 Are you using any framework to generate the response?

Comment: I'm using codecs to generate the binary data, but nothing to generate the response.  Simply using `return ...`  But please enlighten me, I have a feeling there is a much better way to do this.

Comment: @pshep123 You must be using something on Server B to return the response. Python's built-in HTTP server, or something else? There must be something that's *listening* for the incoming requests?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160664/discussion-between-pshep123-and-xyres).

Comment: Main issue was that I needed to customize my response via Flask's `make_response` in which I created custom headers which could then be read by the client.  Thanks for your time and help @xyres!

Comment: @pshep123 Hi, it's been a while, but I just realized you can send the value of `color` itself in a header, instead of the number of bytes it has. I don't know why it slipped my mind then, but it is definitely a simpler solution. But I'm sure you must be done with your project by now, so I just wanted to let you know for future.

Comment: +1. But note that, while sending 6 bytes in the header makes sense, but sending _too much_ will incur a HEAD latency -- which is not desirable.